# Handle different iphone sizes with autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout, screen-resolution

I have a layout designed for iPhone 4S, where, say i have a button with size 60x60. Now i use auto layout here(giving ‘aspect ratio’ constraint for the button) to scale button size to fit different screen sizes of iPhone 5, 6, 6+.

So probably i would get images for 1x, 2x, 3x ie., 60x60, 120x120, 180x180.

But when the button is scaled the size may go 65x65(and this may require image size go 130x130 for 2x and 195x195 for 3x ) or any proportionate size for iPhone 5 and similarly for iPhone 6 and 6+.
So will these images go good for varying button sizes or how this should be handled? Using the same size(60x60) will show the image stretched right.

Can someone please help on adopting graphics for scaling image sizes for different screens.